# Application args not being passed when debugging in VS2017

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to pass command line args to debug my ASP.NET Core application in Visual Studio 2017, but they aren't working. See this screenshot:

[image]

I'm trying to pass `--App:InstanceName demo` as the arguments, but the `args[]` array is empty.

If I have it write the args to the console and run the application from the command line with `./myApp.exe --App:InstanceName demo` then they are correctly passed and output, so it seems to just be a Visual Studio issue.

Edit: Here is the contents of launchSettings.json:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:61313/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "commandLineArgs": "--App:InstanceName demo",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "MyApp": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:58561/"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your `launchSettings.json` file.  Are you sure you are debugging from the same profile where you have configured the args?

Comment: @pariesz Added.

Comment: I could only reproduce using the `IIS Express` profile.  Debugging with the `MyApp` profile applies the args.  Just make sure you copy the 'commandLineArgs' prop to the profile.

Comment: I debug using the IIS Express profile because I need to use Windows Authentication.

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this issue? I am experiencing the same behavior.

Comment: @MikeMoore, no sorry I never found a resolution and just went around testing it another way. The issue seems to be that IIS Express doesn't pass the args it gets onto the .NET Core executable.

Comment: I worked around this by using appsettings.json rather than launchsettings

Comment: I have a similar issue in VS 2022. The commandLineArgs value is not passed to the iiexpress.exe command, which is very, very frustrating. I tried to set it using environment variables (LAUNCHER_ARGS, ANCM_LAUNCHER_ARGS) as well.